# Combine 2 arrays only if their key index match

Tags: php, arrays

**I want to combine this arrays:**

```
$arr1 = array(1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d");
$arr2 = array(1 => 5, 3 => 7, 4 => 9);
```

**I want this:**

```
$arr3 = array("a" => 5, "c" => 7, d => 9);
```

I want to ignore the key index "2" on $arr1 because it doesnt exists on $arr2.

So, I want to combine only if the key index match, combining only values with same original keys.

Comment: Have you even tried something?

Comment: `$res = [];
foreach($arr2 as $k => $v){
    $res[$arr1[$k]] = $v;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d");
$arr2 = array(1 => 5, 3 => 7, 4 => 9);
$arr3 = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($arr2[$key])){
        $arr3[$value] = $arr2[$key];
    }
}

print_r($arr3);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$arr1 = array(1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d");
$arr2 = array(1 => 5, 3 => 7, 4 => 9);
$result = array_combine(array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2), $arr2);
```

Which produces:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 5
    [c] => 7
    [d] => 9
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you would do something like this, its not tested but i'd assume it'll work. What @Adrian said looks better. I didnt use foreach($array as $key=>$val). that is better.

```
//first merge all arrays into one (if you want)
$data = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
$bucket = array();
$ignored = array('2', '3', '4') //array indexes to ignore

foreach($data as $item)
{
    if(in_array($item[$ignored]))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        array_merge($bucket, $item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use "array_key_exists"

```
 $arr1 = array(1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d");
$arr2 = array(1 => 5, 3 => 7, 4 => 9);

foreach($arr1 as $key=>$value)
{
if (array_key_exists($key, $arr2)) {
$arr3[$value]=$arr2[$key];
}
}

print_r($arr3);
```

Array ( [a] => 5 [c] => 7 [d] => 9 )

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function combineArrays( $array1, $array2 ){
    $array3 = array();
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {

        if( isset($array2[$key]) ) { $array3[$value] = $array2[$key]; }

    }

    return $array3;
}
```

use it like:

```
$arr3 = combineArrays($arr1, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way use array_key_exists:

$arr1 = array(1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d");

$arr2 = array(1 => 5, 3 => 7, 4 => 9);

```
$new = array();
foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
     if(array_key_exists($key, $arr1)) {
         $array[$arr1[$key]] = $arr2[$key];
     }
}

 print_r($array);
```

Array ( [a] => 5 [c] => 7 [d] => 9 )

Comment: It would be more logical to loop through $arr2. Wouldn't matter in this case but would be more efficient in larger arrays.

Comment: HI @Christian, you're right, in this case is more logical, i updated my answer, thank you.